How to make indexes using already made embeddings
I'm a novice to ML. I want to use llama_index. I have embeddings. How can I make indexes using those embeddings? I'm using huggingface fine tuned LLM. Please make me correct if I understood something wrong.

Have you tried reading the example in their documentation called Starter Tutorial (Local Models)? It seems very similar to what you want to do.
